# StackExchange is way too confusing and frustrating

Tags: discussion

There are many sites on StackExchange. Way too many. You have a problem with your code, you don't know if you have to go to StackOverflow, CodeReview, Unix or any else website.

This is both confusing and frustrating.

People write questions on StackOverflow and they're told they have to open a new account (even if it's easy once the first is made, the thought of it can disturb most) on another website they've never heard of to ask their question. There is no indication that those websites exist. They have no indication that their question should be posted on another website.

I now even see SE sites on Arduino or Drupal development. What is wrong with merging those into a more general website? They have so much less questions than SO questions over Javascript or C. Why aren't there specific sites on Javascript or C, then? It makes absolutely no sense.

That's for the confusing part.

But SE sites are also frustrating because you're focused on your own problem which is to solve an answer and then what happens? People are nitpicking about which website your question should be posted on. This is just ridiculous: people take the time to nitpick about this nonsense and they don't help you because your question is not bad for this site but would be better on that one. It's just frustrating.

What should be done?

- Merge the websites meaningfully.
- Use tags. Tags are useful and help everyone filter what they want and in search engines, they can scope the question.
- Focus on giving a better experience to users rather than pushing on the nitpicking and dividing the community.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's already officially discouraged to migrate questions off sites where they are on topic merely to find a place where they fit "better". Instead, migration or re-asking questions should only happen if the question isn't actually on topic on the original site at all. So complaining about us doing something that we're already trying to get everyone to avoid doing is rather quixotic.

Comment: Nah, what's really frustrating is the flood of off-topic questions getting in the way of the good content being posted. If a question is legitimately off-topic, how can directing them to where they can actually find the experts to get an answer be a bad thing?

Comment: @gnat Nope, it's not a duplicate of the question tagged as duplicate. This discussion is about the frustration and confusion of people. The other discussion is only about confusion.

Comment: Olivier I don't think the feeling you have regarding the many SE sites affects how  this is or is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks again for posting this, Olivier. The impetus for posting this was very useful feedback for us. But to create a discussion, perhaps just open it up to "I had a pretty awful experience, I understand what happened, how could it be better for someone tomorrow?"

Comment: I'll probably do next time. Thanks @TimPost .

Answer (score 13):

You're correct to be concerned about fragmentation *purely* for the sake of bucketing content into tidy little bins. Doing something purely for the sake of doing it can be awesome if you're climbing a mountain, but not always so useful for practical endeavors.

To wit, I don't disagree with some of what you're saying. I feel like we should be a *little* more relaxed in allowing questions about more *practical* problems that developers face. But we have to take great care - there was once a time when this *was* the case, and the site really was starting to look like it was extremely confused about its purpose. We pushed quite a bit out, I think it could be useful to spend some time examining what might be good to let back in - but that's going to be a long process.

The thing is, you *have* these other wonderful communities, many of which are more relaxed, and lots of *extremely* knowledgeable people running them that *only* want to talk about Linux, or network engineering, or how to clean a fish tank while you're changing your oil. You're not giving your information to another party by joining them - you have a root account from which your membership in additional sites simply stem.

We also do have quite a few rules that aren't obvious from the UI, and some of them are kind of complicated. These were laid like bricks, one by one, each addressing a pretty specific and demonstrated concern. The sum of them, however, might be a wall that's a tad too high. Again - totally valid feedback, but change involves lots and lots of tests, mostly that we still manage to keep certain things out, while looking at how to better support what we inadvertently discouraged.

Anyway, I wanted to chime in as the director of communities to let you know you were heard, and yeah - we do have some work to do. But nothing is perfect, nothing is ever really 'finished' and going forward means a big investment in time spent making sure we don't go backwards :)

Comment: Sorry for the tone I take, but what you say is utopic. People are now empowered to close and they do so happily. Reopening? Naah, too much thinking. Editing, moving? Naah, too hard. The only actions people do are downvoting and close-voting. And I'm not speaking about my questions (given the technicalities of the issues I post, I barely get a comment now): only about questions I feel are interesting and just miss that one thing to make it good. Yet people just don't care and close-vote without any meaningful reason (often the choice offered isn't good enough). What's left? Unanswered questions

Comment: @Olivier you always have the option of editing and improving content yourself. Also, unless you come up with a reasonable solution, this discussion isn't very constructive.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Moving a question is complicated. Most sites don't appreciate being a dumping ground for other sites, so the sites that can be migrated to are limited. Unless the question would be a good question at the target site, it's probably better to close it instead. And people do vote to re-open, they appear in the review queue.

Comment: @PhMgBr I do edit and improve. But the fact that something has been edited/improved is NOT visible. So people blindly follow and close the question. Oh, and good luck to reopen an improved question when the topic is not well known!

Comment: @PhMgBr I wouldn't say it's not constructive. There are plenty of things that I know enough to perceive as inefficient or wrong; my inability to solve those problems shouldn't alienate me from saying "I think this needs someone to solve it" - that's just in general.

Comment: @Olivier if a tag doesn't have enough people that reopen a question, there's something terribly wrong. If people do not deem it worth reopening, maybe there's a policy you're not aware of? Also, editing bumps questions and if closed puts them in a queue that can be reviewed for reopening. I'm not sure more attention than that would work considering how many edits are done everyday in a site like SO.

Comment: @Tim but I haven't seen any general "SE needs improvement" meta posts get something interesting done. It would've been much better if this question focused on something specific, rather than being a 'general impression sharing'.

Comment: @PhMgBr You're right, it's unlikely that this post will lead anyone to a specific solution which we can then implement that solves any one of SE's systemic issues. Posts like Olivier's serve to do something else however; they let those of us who invest time in running the place, both staff and users alike, know what tends to get under people's skin when they try to participate.

Comment: (contd) Even if "general impression sharing" doesn't lead to tangible solutions immediately, it's still critical that we know these perspective are out there, because they help us make better decisions when we do attempt specific, tangible improvements.

Comment: @Ana that's something new! (and pretty nice to hear)